# Saltstack - Parsing YAML properties file to set Jinja variables - For loop

Tags: variables, properties, yaml, jinja2, salt-stack

I try to parse a propertie file with Jinja for setting variables.

I have mutiple categories and sub-categories in this file like :

- jboss_container

  - some properties
  - foobar
- jboss_datasource_install

  - datasource1

    - prop1
    - prop2
  - datasource2
- jboss_app_deploy

  - app1
  - app2

The goal is to set variables from each categories and reuse them in for loop.
--> For Example, i want to install 2 jboss datasources and loop on each sub-categories

**foobar.properties.yml :**

```
jboss_container:
    jboss_container_values:
      jboss_container_install: 'True'
      jboss_app_name: 'foobar'
      jboss_version: 'x.x.x'
      ...

jboss_datasource_install:
    datasource1:
      jboss_datasource_install: 'True'
      jboss_datasource_name: 'foobar'
      jboss_datasource_jta: 'true'
      ...
    datasource2:
      jboss_datasource_install: 'True'
      ...
```

**init.sls :**

```
{% import_yaml 'foobar_properties.yml' as jboss_apps %}

% for jboss_container, jboss_container_values in jboss_apps.iteritems() %}
      {% for key, value in jboss_container_values.items() %}
                  {% if value.get('jboss_container_install') != 'False' %}

# Do stuff - {{ value.jboss_app_name }}

                  {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% for jboss_datasource_install, jboss_datasource_install_name in jboss_apps.iteritems() %}
      {% for key, value in jboss_datasource_install_name.items() %}
                  {% if value.get('jboss_datasource_install') != 'False' %}

# Do stuff - {{ value.jboss_datasource_install }}

                  {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Actually occurs this error in Salt :

***Jinja variable 'dict object' has no attribute 'jboss_app_name'***

Any Ideas How to do this?

Many thanks :)

**UPD:**

Unfortunately with :

```
{% for key, value in jboss_apps['jboss_container']['jboss_container_values'].iteritems() %} 
{% if value.get('jboss_container_install') == 'True' %}
# Do stuff - {{ value.jboss_app_name }}
```

I got this error : `failed: Jinja variable 'str object' has no attribute 'get'`

Without the If statement, I got this error : `failed: Jinja variable 'str object' has no attribute 'jboss_app_name'`

And if i try with `{{ jboss_app_name }}` rather than `{{ value.jboss_app_name }}`, same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop iterates through `jboss_datasource_install` and your inner loop through `datasource1`. Your `if` then asks for

```
value.get('jboss_container_install')
```

The dict does not contain a key named `jboss_container_install`, so it returns `None`. And since that does not equal `'False'`, Jinja then attempts to insert `value.jboss_app_name`, which is where the error comes from.

A simple fix would be to rewrite the `if`-Statement to:

```
{% if value.get('jboss_container_install') == 'True' %}
```

But your outer loop seems strange anyway. If you only want to iterate through `jboss_container`, you can replace

```
{% for jboss_container, jboss_container_values in jboss_apps.iteritems() %}
  {% for key, value in jboss_container_values.items() %}
```

with

```
{% for key, value in jboss_apps['jboss_container']['jboss_container_values'].iteritems() %}
```

Comment: The fix with value == True works perfectly for me. Thanks

Comment: But {% for key, value in jboss_apps['jboss_container']['jboss_container_values'] %} failed with error : failed: Jinja error: too many values to unpack

Comment: There was an `iteritems()` missing, I fixed it.